# Concurrent reading and processing file line by line in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, concurrency, parallel-processing

Suppose I need to apply two functions `f: String => A` and `g: A => B` to each line in a large text file to create eventually a list of `B`.

Since the file is large and `f` and `g` are expensive I would like to make the processing concurrent. I can use "parallel collections" and do something like `io.Source.fromFile("data.txt").getLines.toList.par.map(l => g(f(l))` but it does not execute reading the file, `f`, and `g` concurrently.

What is the best way to implement concurrency in this example?

Comment: Why break it up that way instead of having each thread handle all aspects of, say, blocks of 10 lines at a time?

Comment: @RexKerr Ok. Suppose I would like to process blocks of 10 lines at a time. I am reading file line by line, when I have read 10 lines, I spawn an actor to process them, send the block to it asynchronously and get the Future. Once I finished reading I call all futures to get the results. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` on `Future`:

```
val futures = io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.map{ s => Future{ stringToA(s) }.map{ aToB } }.toIndexedSeq

val results = futures.map{ Await.result(_, 10 seconds) }
// alternatively:
val results = Await.result(Future.sequence(futures), 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks. However `stringToA` and `aToB` do not in parallel here, do they?

Comment: @Michael: They do. `Map` on `Future` creates new `Future` when target one is completed. So `stringToA` and `aToB` will be executed in different threads. I don't know if this behavior is useful for you.

Comment: @Michael: Are you sure that my answer is what you want? With `Future` you may use your configured `ExecutionContext`. And `map` on future allows you to split tasks (it could be helpful for threadpool). But @dhg gives you a simple solution. It could be better if you don't have to configure `ExecutionContext` and split tasks.

Answer (score 14):

First, an important note: Don't use `.par` on `List` since it requires copying all the data (since `List` can only be read sequentially).  Instead, use something like `Vector`, for which the `.par` conversion can happen without the copying.

It seems like you're thinking of the parallelism the wrong way.  Here's what would happen:

If you have a file like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And functions `f` and `g`:

```
def f(line: String) = {
  println("running f(%s)".format(line))
  line.toInt
}

def g(n: Int) = {
  println("running g(%d)".format(n))
  n + 1
}
```

Then you can do:

```
io.Source.fromFile("data.txt").getLines.toIndexedSeq[String].par.map(l => g(f(l)))
```

And get output:

```
running f(3)
running f(0)
running f(5)
running f(2)
running f(6)
running f(1)
running g(2)
running f(4)
running f(7)
running g(4)
running g(1)
running g(6)
running g(3)
running g(5)
running g(0)
running g(7)
running f(9)
running f(8)
running g(9)
running g(8)
```

So even though the entire `g(f(l))` operation is happening on the same thread, you can see that *each line* may be processed in parallel.  Thus, many `f` and `g` operations can be happening simultaneously on separate threads, but the `f` and `g` for a *particular line* will happen in sequentially.

This is, after all, the way you should expect since there's actually no way that it could read the line, run `f`, and run `g` in parallel.  For example, how could it execute `g` on the output of `f` if the line hasn't yet been read?