# process bunch of string effective

Tags: performance, scala, collections

I need to read some data from a file in chuck of 128M, and then for each line, I will do some processing, naive way to do is using split to convert the string into collection of lines and then process each line, but maybe that is not effective as it will create a collection which simply stores the temp result which could be costy. Is there is a way with better performance?

The file is huge, so I kicked off several thread, each thread will pick up 128 chuck, in the following script rawString is a chuck of 128M.

```
randomAccessFile.seek(start)
randomAccessFile.read(byteBuffer)
val rawString = new String(byteBuffer)
val lines=rawString.split("\n")
for(line <- lines){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're going to do with the trailing bits of lines at the beginning and end of the chunk.  I'll leave that to you to figure out--this solution captures everything delimited on both sides by `\n`.

Anyway, assuming that `byteBuffer` is actually an array of bytes and not a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, and that you're okay with just handling Unix line encodings, you would want to

```
def lines(bs: Array[Byte]): Array[String] = {
  val xs = Array.newBuilder[Int]
  var i = 0
  while (i<bs.length) {
    if (bs(i)=='\n') xs += i
    i += 1
  }
  val ix = xs.result
  val ss = new Array[String](0 max (ix.length-1))
  i = 1
  while (i < ix.length) {
    ss(i-1) = new String(bs, ix(i-1)+1, ix(i)-ix(i-1)-1)
    i += 1
  }
  ss
}
```

Of course this is rather long and messy code, but if you're really worried about performance this sort of thing (heavy use of low-level operations on primitives) is the way to go.  (This also takes only ~3x the memory of the chunk on disk instead of ~5x (for mostly/entirely ASCII data) since you don't need the full string representation around.)

Comment: when using your approach: val stringArray=lines(byteBuffer), it throws error of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. The original approach doesn't have this error.

Comment: @DanielWu - I changed the array allocation approach to what I originally intended.  That should fix it (no wasted space).

Comment: The file I read is size of 128M, and the max heap is 16G, but still error out because of memory.java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)

Comment: I printed some info for every 1000 lines processed, and found it throw out of memory when process more than 10k rows.  
  while (i < ix.length) {
    ss(i-1) += new String(bs, ix(i-1)+1, ix(i))
    i += 1
    if (i%1000==0) println(i)
  }

Comment: @DanielWu - Sorry, wrong limit--it takes a length, not an ending index.  Fixed now.

Comment: @DanielWu - And switched a `+=` that should have been a `=`, and tested it, so it should _actually_ work now.

Comment: Thanks Rex, that's really work. And it took 12 seconds to process 96M data. Do you think the performance is good or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30066/discussion-between-daniel-wu-and-rex-kerr)

Comment: For your comment "This also takes only ~3x the memory of the chunk on disk instead of ~5x (for mostly/entirely ASCII data since you don't need the full string representation around.)".  But in your code, all the bytes are represented as string in an array, so what do you mean by "don't need the full string representation around"?

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better to read text line by line:

```
import scala.io.Source
for(line <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: As the file is big, I split the file in 128 per chuck, each chuck will be processed by one thread, so I can't use Source.fromFile("file.txt")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843015/concurrent-reading-and-processing-file-line-by-line-in-scala looks like helpful.